# How can i get my graphics card to work?

Tags: 12.04, boot, graphics

Okay, so i have an old graphics card that i decided to use in another computer. The problem is, the computer doesn't detect it. at all. in legacy mode, nope. uefi, nope. It doesn't even switch over to it when automatically booting ubuntu in legacy mode. it stays on motherboard graphics. The graphics card is humming away, and has a 450w power supply (100 watts more than recommended for this card). 
Tried: 
`sudo lshw > hardware.011509
nano hardware.011509`

It listed the pciex16 as empty. 
Putting it in another motherboard, it worked. (ubuntu, not windows) (Same psu)
putting the bios in legacy mode. did not switch over to the card (stayed on integrated graphics) and did not detect it.
turned off fast boot in windows, no change
turned off secure boot, no change
turned on load legacy OPROMS, and then enabled legacy boot mode. no change, still doesn't work.
There is no quick boot option in BIOS.
Please help?

Comment: Guys?
Any help?

Comment: bump
Cmon guys, please

Comment: bump...
still an issue

Comment: bump! ... driving me crazy

Comment: Really, guys? Please